# Getting HTML Menu Centered on Screen

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems getting my menu to center on the screen. I thought setting the display to block, and making the left and right margins to auto, would do this for me; however, I was wrong.  Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bou2p810/) to help show the problem.  Thanks for the help.

```
<ul id="menuList">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


#menuList{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#menuList ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menuList li
{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#menuList a
{
    display: block;
    width: 8em;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set menu to `inline-block` and parent to `text-align:center`

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/bou2p810/2/)

replace `body` with your `parent` `id` or `class`

```
body {
    text-align:center;
}
#menuList {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @JasonW Please reconsider. This is NOT a good idea. You'll have to insert a CSS rule that overrides that text-align center on every element. That's way too much overhead, for a problem that could be easily solved. (See my answer.)

Comment: As I mentioned Vitorino may have had his example as text-align the body, but his wording above the code says to the parent element.  In this case my parent element on contains my menu; leaving my body untouched by the text-align

Answer (score 2):

The best way to center an element is by using `margin: 0 auto;` but the element need to have a fixed width (not 100% as you have).

So just add:

```
#menuList {
    width:408px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vitorino's answer is generally a bad idea. You don't want to put text-align: center on your body.

You could, however, set that CSS on the ul, and display the menu items inline(-block). [As such](http://jsfiddle.net/bou2p810/3/).

```
#menuList ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#menuList li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Vitorino's answer was just to put the text-align:center on the parent element of the menu; which in my case is not the body.  This parent element only contains the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the width, example:

```
#menuList{
    display:block;
    width:70%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You used display block, so that your elements start new line, and then floats, that they would stay in same line. Just don't use this weird combo.
If you need items stay in line use 'display:inline;'
if you need items to stick to either left or right side of parent element, use floats. Be careful as floats often mess all the thing up. There are other ways to float things, that doesn't pull them out of document flow.
Here is fixed CSS:

```
    #menuList{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#menuList ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menuList li
{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#menuList a
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8em;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```